# How can I efficiently filter large amounts of data from an sqlite DB into numpy arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, sqlite

I use a program that outputs data into an sqlite database. For my needs, the data in the existing database is not formatted well, so I am doing some preprocessing which will be inserted into a new table. See below:

**Input** (there are more columns not shown, and this table is actually a join of three, if that matters)

| First Name | Last Name | State | Start Time | Stop Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | Smith | NV | 0 | 5 |
| Bill | Smith | NV | 12 | 15 |
| Bill | Smith | NV | 7 | 8 |
| Bill | Smith | NV | 45 | 47 |
| Maggie | Tangerine | MI | 3 | 7 |
| Maggie | Tangerine | MI | 68 | 90 |
| Bill | Smith | NV | 60 | 66 |

**Desired output**

| First Name | Last Name | Times |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | Smith | np.array(0,5,12,15,7,8,45,47,60,66) |
| Maggie | Tangerine | np.array(3,7,68,90) |

Right now what I tried first was a query to pull the data for a specific name before inserting into the new table:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('''
                         SELECT StartTime,StopTime
                         FROM Input
                         INNER JOIN Input1 
                         ON ... 
                         INNER JOIN Input2 
                         ON ... 
                         WHERE FirstName = ?
                         LastName = ?
                         State = ?
                         ''', conn, params=(first,last,state))
        
np.concat(np.unique(df[0].values.flatten()),np.unique(df[1].values.flatten()))
```

This is going to be really terrible for efficiency, since the query for one set of names takes just slightly less than a query for all the names. Would it be better to try and pull the times for a specific name from the pandas dataframe? Is there some other way to do this I am not thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

yeah, i would look into trying to query all the data without a where clause specifying the name, state and add a group by claus at the end.
"Group by firstname, lastname, state"

Comment: I think I would need to use group_concat, but I wasn't sure if that would have better performance than manipulating the pandas dataframe